# Is it possible to reference a PySpark DataFrame using it's rdd id?

Tags: pyspark, rdd

If I "overwrite" a df using the same naming convention in PySpark such as in the example below, am I able to reference it later on using the rdd id?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('Abraham','Lincoln')], ['first_name', 'last_name'])
df.checkpoint()
print(df.show())
print(df.rdd.id())

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = df.select(names.first_name,names.last_name,concat_ws(' ', names.first_name, names.last_name).alias('full_name'))
df.checkpoint()
print(df.show())
print(df.rdd.id())
```

Comment: Is that possible in python? no.

Comment: Definitely no @Lamanus. This a PySpark only functionality.